sed - Posix compliant generic multiple insert/appends single command
I'd like to perform multiple inserts/appends in a single sed command that is portable.
In GNU sed, I can do something like:
sed -e '1i hi' -e '$a bye' <(seq 1 10)
I've the found the following works, but I'm not sure if it's the correct/best way to handle it in Posix compliant sed:
sed --posix '1{x;s/$/hi/;G};//h;${x;s/$/\nbye/}' <(seq 1 10)
--or--
sed --posix '1{x;s/$/hi/;G};${s/$/\nbye/}' <(seq 1 10)
I've not seen anyone really discuss how to delete the hold space, took a guess - is this the best way to effect this in all posix compliant seds?
Update: since \n on RHS is not portable, looks like it's going to take multi-lines:
sed --posix '1{x;s/$/hi/;G};${s/$/\
> bye/}' <(seq 1 10)

Update:
Ok, guess I found a way to add newline by grabbing it in a hold on the LHS - kinda ugly though:
sed '1{G;s/\(.\)\(\n\)/hi\2\1/;};${G;s/\(.\)\(\n\)/\1\2bye/;}' <(seq 1 10)

or this, a little better:
sed '1{G;s/\([^\n]*\)\(\n\)/hi\2\1/;};${G;s/\(\n\)/\1bye/;}' <(seq 1 10)

Answer - Settled on Potong's parameter expansion version, looks posix compliant:
sed --posix $'1i\\hi\n;$a\\bye' <(seq 1 10)

One liner is preferred

\n in replacement is not portable; it's only allowed in the regex

Yea, I see - according to https://sed.sourceforge.io/grabbag/tutorials/sedfaq.txt I'd need to put it on multiple lines to embed a newline generically.

eval "$(printf 'newline="\n"')"; sed '...'"${newline}"'...' ... or sed "$(printf '...\n...')" ... (need to escape other printf format string metacharacters)

sed is great for s/old/new on individual lines, for anything else (i.e. any time you find yourself talking about "hold space" or using sed instructions other than "s", "g", and "p") just use awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, maintainability, etc., etc.

@Ed Yea, probably not easily maintainable when you stray into some of the lesser known commands. I find insert/append/delete fairly easy to deal with - HhxgG aren't bad when you wrap your brain around hold/pattern space swapping but most people aren't familiar with them.

@AdamD. part of my point is that even if insert/append/delete and HhxgG aren't bad once you wrap your brain around hold/pattern space swapping, they're still better avoided since the same functionality is simpler, clearer, easier to maintain/enhance, and more portable in awk and awk and sed are both mandatory POSIX tools so if you have sed then you also have awk.

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):
sed $'1i\\hi\n$a\\bye' file

or
sed '1G;1s/\(.*\)\(.\)/hi\2\1/;$G;$s/$/bye/' file

or
sed '1h;1s/.*/hi/p;1g;$a\bye' file

or
sed 'H;1h;$!d;s/.*/hi/;G;a\bye' file

or
sed '1{x;s/^/hi/p;x};${p;s/.*/bye/}' file


Thanks buddy! First one, is what I was looking for..

Golfed down to: sed $'1ihi\n;$abye' <(seq 1 10)

Since the newline is from the shell the ; can also be done away with. I put the double backslashes to make the solution posix compliant.


Yea, that's probably golf-maxed.


The GNUism in the first command is that i and a accept the line to be inserted on the same line, while POSIX requires them to be on separate lines. This should be conformant:
sed -e '1i \
hi' -e '$a \
bye' <(seq 1 10) 

or
sed '1i \
hi
$a \
bye' <(seq 1 10) 


Looks good, guess I was trying to keep it on one line. On multiple lines could probably also drop the -e's sed --posix '1i \ hi $a \ bye' <(seq 1 10)

@AdamD. As long as hi is on its own line ($a on a new line), yes

Yes, that's how I typed it but the comments collapse. Thanks, looks like multi-line is going to be required.

Unfortunately, MacOS does not support the --posix option, but other than that, this seems to work on Macs, too.

@tripleee Yeah, --posix is just to make GNU sed reject GNUisms, let me remove that...

May I respectfully suggest that you consider Awk instead?
awk 'BEGIN { print "hi" } 1; END { print "bye" }' file


I had a Perl suggestion too, but it turns out that perl -i~ -pe 'BEGIN { print "hi\n"; } END { print "bye\n"; }' poo does not add hi and bye to poo (!)

awk is probably better for this, but I'm trying to limit the amount of dependencies - already dealing w/sed in various places.

@AdamD. to limit the dependencies you should use awk instead of sed everywhere since, like sed but unlike perl, python, ruby, etc.,  awk is also a mandatory POSIX tool and it can do anything sed (and grep, seq, tr, wc, and many other text-processing tools) can do, usually with simpler, clearer, more portable and easier to enhance/maintain syntax, but the opposite isn't true.

@EdMorton @AdamD. awk is even in BusyBox, as I speculate from @AdamD.'s requirements that could also be an indicator of suitability in the POSIX/Embedded/constrained environment.
